# How to request refund of fees from USCIS due to USCIS mistake?

Tags: usa

I had to file a form (I-824 for 465$) which was required entirely due to a mistake by USCIS.

Since I would not have needed to file the form without USCIS mistake, I would like to request a refund for the 465$ (now that my case has been processed).

How do I do that?

Comment: What was the USCIS mistake? And why did you pay the fees and not challenge their mistake if you knew of that before filing the form that you filed?

Comment: It's *not* important for this question but still, it's described here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20426/i-130-approved-i-797-received-why-do-we-have-to-file-i-824-and-do-we. I called numerous times, set tickets but the response was "sorry you have to file this form". It might have been possible to continue fighting with the risk of loosing more and more months possibly without success. I have been advised to move forward to avoid months or even years of delay and request the refund afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the [USCIS website says about refunds](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/filing-fees):

> When you send a payment, you agree to pay for a government service.
> Filing and biometric service fees are final and non-refundable,
> regardless of any action we take on your application, petition, or
> request, or if you withdraw your request. Please refer to the form you
> filed for additional information, or you may call the USCIS Contact
> Center at 800-375-5283 (for people who are deaf, hard of hearing, or
> have a speech disability: TTY 800-767-1833).

So the action you can take is to call them. However, I'm not optimistic about your chances of getting a refund based on other cases I've heard of USCIS mistakes. USCIS's text above even says outright that they aren't accountable like that: "...fees are final and non-refundable, regardless of any action we take on your application..."